# Trying to run a spark-submit job on a yarn cluster but I keep getting the following warning. How do I fix the issue?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

```
WARN YarnClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check 
your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient 
resources.
```

I have looked through similar questions and tried everything else that was mentioned. When I look through the yarn-nodemanager log on hdfs I see the following warning that might be causing the error. How do I fix these warnings?

```
2017-09-13 14:29:52,640 WARN 
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: The 
Auxilurary Service named 'mapreduce_shuffle' in the configuration is for class 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler which has a name of 'httpshuffle'. 
Because these are not the same tools trying to send ServiceData and read 
Service Meta Data may have issues unless the refer to the name in the config.
```

yarn-site.xml log:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common
/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, 
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/
hdfs/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, 
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoo
p/mapreduce/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*, 
/usr/local/hadoop
/share/hadoop/yarn/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
   <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
<description>
  Number of seconds after an application finishes before the nodemanager's
  DeletionService will delete the application's localized file directory
  and log directory.
```

core-site.xml log:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://sandbox:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml log:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Please let me know if I am trying to find a solution to my initial warning in the wrong direction because the application keeps running but no data is sent to hdfs. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the warning by adding the following property to hdfs-site.xml: 
      <property>
           <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
            <value>0.0.0.0</value>
       </property>
However, I still get the same intial warning with no data being transferred to hdfs.

Comment: Did you fix it?